# PHP printer, printer_write works, printer_draw_text isn't

Tags: php, printing

I'm looking to achieve some kind of a template for invoice through php_printer to be sent auto to the printer. After hours i managed to get the thing going + solved the encoding issue (i need Greek) but i don't seem to understand why would `printer_write` work and `printer_draw_text` isn't.

I need to be able to draw new lines and asign some left and right but `printer_write` seems to be overwriting everything that is already in the document.

One thing to notice is the fact that if i add a

```
printer_start_doc($handle, "My Document");
printer_start_page($handle);

printer_end_page($handle);
printer_end_doc($handle);
```

Everything on the file is messed up with the PRINTER info being on top and then below are nonesense.

Below is the code i'm running

```
$handle = printer_open("Emulator");
printer_set_option($handle, PRINTER_MODE, "raw"); 
$font = printer_create_font("@Batang", 148, 76, PRINTER_FW_MEDIUM, false, false, false, -50);
printer_select_font($handle, $font);        
$sql = mysql_query("...")or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $lineofText = 'x'.$row['salelines_units'].' '.getProductName($row['salelines_product']).' $ '.$row['salelines_price'];
    printer_draw_text($handle, $lineofText, 10, 10);
}
//printer_write($handle,$print);
printer_close($handle);
```

This won't send anything to the printer. If i remove the `printer_write` from comments it prints the `$print` variable.

EDIT: Even if i use `start_doc and start_page` and print nothing i still get all the printer info and document info at the top but then all symbols and something 320W